# Graphical DIFF programs for linux

Tags: linux, user-interface, diff, suse

I really like **Araxis** Merge for a graphical DIFF program for the PC. I have no idea what's available for **linux**, though.  We're running SUSE linux on our z800 mainframe.
I'd be most grateful if I could get a few pointers to what programs everyone else likes.

Comment: Nobody has mentioned tkdiff. Surprise! It is blazing fast compared to meld.

Comment: I'm sorry. But this question is very constructive. Although it could be qualified as off-topic

Comment: Helpful here too. And I would think "supported by ... expertise..."

Comment: There are way more visual diff tools for Linux than those mentioned here, and Windows tools work quite well via Wine. However, [all the Linux visual diff tools that I've tried are extremely slow at comparing large files](https://wiki.dandascalescu.com/reviews/software/diffuse_-_the_one_best_visual_diff_tool_for_linux) - on the order of 30+ seconds vs. 1 second for a Windows tool.

Answer (score 246):

I know of two graphical diff programs: [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) and [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/). I haven't used KDiff3, but Meld works well for me.

It seems that both are in the standard package repositories for openSUSE 11.0

Comment: I've found Meld to be pretty powerful also, although it does tend to be a sluggish on very large files.

Comment: I like the SUbversion integration of Meld. If you open your current folder then you see a list of files that have changed since your last check-in. Very practical.

Comment: +1 for Meld - really slick. Definitely one of the more readable GUI diff apps that I've used.

Comment: If you compere line by line, Meld is good. But if you make more changes on file meld can't find changes correctly. I think BeyondCompare best from Meld.

Comment: Meld just refuses to diff anything that has even a single byte of binary data. Useless for the PDF files I'm trying to diff.

Comment: What if there is no file? I just want to copy the text from clipboard. Neither supports that. They need only files.

Answer (score 50):

If you use Vim, you can use the inbuilt diff functionality. `vim -d file1 file2` takes you right into the diff screen, where you can do all sort of merge and deletes.

Comment: The prime advantage of using an editor to 'diff' files is that you can manually edit the files in place.

Additionally, VIM automatic diff folding lets you see just the differences and expand the hidden code only when you need it.

Comment: I quite often use this capability, although with Meld it is much easier to merge as you often can just click one of the arrows and you're there.

Comment: This in my opinion is the best answer. Thank you sir. +1 for a solution with Vim.

Answer (score 44):

[BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php) has also just been released in a Linux version.

Not free, but the Windows version is worth every penny - I'm assuming the Linux version is the same.

Comment: BeyondCompare is great IMO, better than all the integrated-with-version-control diff tools and ide-packaged or OS standard diff tools I've ever used. +1

Comment: This is a great windows app, I've never used it on Linux.

Comment: BeyondCompare works well on Linux and IMO is superior to meld

Comment: Meld is nice if there are only a few changes to the file but seems to get easily confused so I tried BeyondCompare, For me in this case it did no better and I prefer Melds interface.

Comment: Tried BeyondCompare on linux and has strange behavior. Shows conflicts when it could solve it itself. Also applying changes i strange. The lower pannel does not stay in sync with the upper ones

Answer (score 30):

[Diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/) is also very good.
It even lets you easily adjust how lines are matched up,
by defining match-points.

Comment: Being able to manually adjust the match points is a really great feature!

Comment: I just tried diffuse and it gave saner comparison results than meld on a file where a block was moved into an if statement (+1). However, you can't point diffuse at 2 directories, it's files only (-1).

Comment: the only tool (apart form `vimdiff`) that allows merging/diffing unlimited amount of files, to my knowledge. net is `kdiff3` with max 4 files.

Answer (score 18):

Emacs comes with [Ediff](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/ediff.html).

Here is what Ediff looks like [image: EdiffScreenshot]

Comment: ediff is amazing, and the integration with emacs is sweet

Comment: It's pretty hard to setup the way one likes it, and by default it looks like a Christmas tree, it isn't obvious. And that comment from an Emacs zealot.

Comment: In case anyone dislike default ediff setup. 
```;; don't start another frame
(setq ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain)
;; put windows side by side
(setq ediff-split-window-function (quote split-window-horizontally))``` [source](http://pragmaticemacs.com/emacs/visualise-and-copy-differences-between-files/)

Answer (score 15):

[Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) and [KDiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) are two of the most popular.

Answer (score 6):

[xxdiff](http://furius.ca/xxdiff/) is lightweight if that's what you're after.

Comment: xxdiff is also equipped with features for make code reviews, and has been built from the ground up to be integrated with scripts (see, for example, "decision mode" and the accompanying Python library that comes with it, with many examples of automated invocation).

It's lightweight in that it's written in C, so it runs fast, and it doesn't depend on desktop environments (written against Qt only).

Answer (score 4):

I have used Meld once, which seemed very nice, and I may try more often. vimdiff works well, if you know vim well. Lastly I would mention I've found xxdiff does a reasonable job for a quick comparison. There are many diff programs out there which do a good job.

Answer (score 3):

[Kompare](http://www.caffeinated.me.uk/kompare/) is fine for diff, but I use [dirdiff](http://freshmeat.net/projects/dirdiff/). Although it looks ugly, dirdiff can do 3-way merge - and you can get everything done inside the tool (both diff and merge).

Answer (score 1):

There is [DiffMerge from SourceGear](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/). It's pretty good.  Araxis Merge is one of the programs I miss from Windows.  I wonder if it works under Wine ;)  Might have to give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Subclipse for Eclipse has an excellent graphical diff plugin if you are using SVN (subversion) source control.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Guiffy](http://guiffy.org/) and it works well.
 [image]
<sub>(source: [guiffy.org](http://guiffy.org/images/CompareReportInFFThumb.jpg))</sub>

Comment: We used to Guiffy at work until we discovered several very serious issues with it. For example, on large files it may merge part of the file, then just fail, leaving a partially merged file. It had even more interesting issues as well, like graphical ">" characters becoming a part of the merge.

Answer (score 0):

I generally need to diff codes from subversion repositories and so far eclipse has worked really nicely for me... I use KDiff3 for other works.

Comment: Just a note on KDiff3:  It works well to compare files, however, the merging needs to be rewritten with a brain.  Merged files are routinely not saved after saving and the workflow is somewhere between clunky and completely worthless.  Save your self the countless hours of frustration and lost productivity and use ANYTHING else.